# Viewing hair in rendered mode whilst in particle edit

Tags: rendering, hair

I wanted to preview my hair in cycles rendered mode as I edited in real time side by side, however, once I enter the particle edit mode the rendered mode doesn't have any hair: [image]
I searched up for similar issues, and they suggest enabling overlays, but, that doesn't give me rendered hair in my rendered view, it gives me editing strands:

[image]

Is this a currently impossible thing or is there a setting combo I'm missing?

Comment: It is not possible. You can have different view angles and shading methods in separate windows, but not different modes. I guess for the simple reason that you should not edit the mesh in one window while in the other you could possibly be changing the weight painting for example. That said, I do not know if this is intentionally made like this or technically limited. We are just users, no developers here so we can only speculate.

Comment: There is a tool setting option to see the particle children in *Particle Edit* mode (side panel > *Tool > Options > [X] Children* checkbox). But you will see them in every view. This option can cause lag in viewport when too many children are displayed.